# Summarise whether a value is contained in multiple other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am investigating a large dataset with 100+ columns. One set of columns contain integers where the integers are not repeated across columns. For example, the number 6 may or may not appear in a row, but it will only appear once across the columns.

An example mock-up (bearing in mind that there are hundreds of other, non-related columns surrounding these):

```
> x1 <- c(1,6,4,5)
> x2 <- c(6,0,11,3)
> x3 <- c(5,0,9,6)
> df <- data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3))
> df
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  6  5
2  6  0  0
3  4 11  9
4  5  3  6
```

Ideally using dplyr (since I am trying to become more "fluent"), how would I most cleanly create a new column to indicate whether or not a 6 was contained in the other columns? I am hesitant to use a function like reshape2's melt given the 100s of other columns in the dataset.

My current, messy, solution:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- mutate(df, Contains6 = (x1 == 6) + (x2 == 6) + (x3 == 6),
+              Contains6 = revalue(as.factor(as.character(Contains6)), 
+                                  c("0"="No","1"="Yes")))
> df
  x1 x2 x3 Contains6
1  1  6  5       Yes
2  6  0  0       Yes
3  4 11  9        No
4  5  3  6       Yes
```

Possible extension to this: would there be a clean, programmatic way of creating similar columns for all values contained in x1:x3, e.g. Contains1, Contains4, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
df$Contains6 <- c("no", "yes")[(apply(df==6, 1, any))+1L]
df$Contains6
#[1] "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes"
```

If we need to create multiple "Contains" columns, we can loop with `lapply`

```
v1 <- c(1,4,6)
df[paste0("Contains", v1)] <- lapply(v1, function(i) 
           c('no', 'yes')[(apply(df==i, 1, any))+1L])
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks so much. And if you needed to specify the range of columns to apply the function to? (Since there are more columns in the data beyond x1, x2 and x3).

Comment: @uk_user You can subset the columns i.e. `apply(df[paste0('x', 1:3)], 1, ...` or use the numeric index of the columns in the dataset.